# How to fix errant orientation and points in an elliptical particle cloud?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, geometry, particle-system

I'm creating an elliptical cloud of points in Three.js and have two problems that seem straight forward, but I've been stuck on now for a couple days:

1. The cloud should be elliptically shaped with the **longest** axis on the `x` axis - currently it's oriented with the **shortest** axis on the `x` axis
2. While my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/e9J9Q/) for the cloud looks perfectly elliptical, the working code in my file has a few points at `y = 0` on the `x` axis that appear to be running to the beat of their own drummer - they are lined up like soldiers on the `y = 0` on either side of the ellipse to the measure of `length` (see screenshot below). Both files contain the same math for the ellipse - what's going on here?

Thanks!

The code for the elliptical cloud of points:

```
particleCount = 300;
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
    // ELLIPTICAL
    var length = 200; // x (major axis)
    var width = 75; // y (minor axis)
    var pX = (Math.random() * length);
    // solve for length of vertical chord at pX:
    var chord;
    var rightBisector = Math.abs((length/2) - pX);
    chord = (2 * length) * Math.sqrt(1 - Math.exp(2 * Math.log(rightBisector/width)));
    var pY = (Math.random() * chord);
    pX -= length/2; // center the cloud horizontally
    pY -= chord/2; // center the cloud vertically
    // END ELLIPTICAL
    // Make image particle at pX, pY and add to system
```

[image: elliptical cloud of points with errant particles on either side]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all the errors lay in my misunderstanding of the ellipse equation someone kindly aided me on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/874893/165755). I've corrected the code below now realizing that I used the dimensions of the axes in places where I should have used the two different radii. I've edited some of the variable names to make things clearer.

```
// ELLIPTICAL particle cloud
var majorAxis = 200; // x (major axis)
var minorAxis = 75; // y (minor axis)
var majorRadius = majorAxis / 2;
var minorRadius = minorAxis / 2;
var pX = ( Math.random() * majorAxis );
// solve for length of vertical chord at pX:
var rightBisector = Math.abs( majorRadius - pX );
var chord = (2 * minorRadius) * Math.sqrt( 1 - Math.exp( 2 * Math.log( rightBisector / majorRadius ) ) );
var pY = ( Math.random() * chord );
pX -= majorRadius; // center the cloud horizontally
pY -= chord / 2; // center the cloud vertically
// END ELLIPTICAL
// Make image particle at pX, pY and add to system
```

Now all is as it should be:

[image: corrected ellipse]